# The best and flexible android app development framework

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am new deciding to learn how to make android Apps using CSS, HTML and Javascrip as i only know these.

Could you please help selecting which are the best and flexible framework to learn?

Before asking here, i have visited phoneGap and found below quotation which makes me confuse since Android's current version is 5.0*.

> Cordova supports Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API level 10) and 4.x. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard. Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5% threshold. [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create android apps with only html, css and JS. Even then the 3 web stacks isn't the only technology you will be using, even though take a look at :

1. [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)
2. [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html)
3. [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html)

But you should understand, you will easily create simple apps using these technologies. But for creating a bit more complex apps, just the 3 web tech knowledge isn't enough